# Return captcha in controller in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony

I have an action on a controller in symfony 3.4 that returns an image created with text, the problem is that when I see the image in the browser you see a small white square with nothing, I do not receive any type of error.

The code :

```
<?php

namespace Programas\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CaptchaController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'image/png');

        #

        $word = "";

        $image = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 500);

        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);  
        imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,200,50,$background_color);

        $line_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 64,64,64); 
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
            imageline($image,0,rand()%50,200,rand()%50,$line_color);
        }

        $pixel_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,255);
        for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++) {
            imagesetpixel($image,rand()%200,rand()%50,$pixel_color);
        }  

        $letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        $len = strlen($letters);
        $letter = $letters[rand(0, $len-1)];

        $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);

        for ($i = 0; $i< 6;$i++) {
            $letter = $letters[rand(0, $len-1)];
            imagestring($image, 5,  5+($i*30), 20, $letter, $text_color);
            $word.=$letter;
        }

        ImagePng($image);

        #

        ob_start();

        imagepng($image);

        $imagevariable = ob_get_contents(); 

        ob_end_clean(); 

        ImageDestroy($image);

        $response->setContent($imagevariable); 

        return $response;
    }
}
```

How can I show the display of the image correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier and better to use the captcha Bundle and use the "captcha" in your form type.

https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle

Then you can use it like this `$builder->add('captcha', CaptchaType::class);`

I'm sure that there are some other good bundles but what you try is not the best way. Normally you have to extend your Form Builder and render a captcha field. You can take a look at the bundle how they solve it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the issue is that I want to learn how to make my own captcha

Comment: Yes but you need that Captcha in a form... and for that you have to extend the Form Builder...